# 'JSON' is undefined error in IE only

Tags: ajax, wcf, json, internet-explorer

I'm making an AJAX call to a WCF service and when I pass in my data i use JSON.stringify()

The call returns and works fine in FF, & Chrome, but not IE8.  I get an error:  'JSON' is undefined

suggestions?

p.s. I also want this to work in IE7

Comment: I don't think IE8 supports the `stringify()` method natively (there are libraries that implement it, but you haven't specified whether you're using any of them)

Comment: it does.  Look under 'cross-domain security' here:  http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/developers-new.aspx

Comment: Refer to the following 
        http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/resolve-json-is-undefined-error-in.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use json2 for a consistent cross browser implementation.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: would I reference JSON the same way?  Will it conflict with IE8's native implementation?

Comment: Yes. No (it checks for an existing JSON object). If IE has an implementation then I don't know why you are getting JSON undefined error (is it called something else?). I don't know enough about IE to comment further.

Comment: IE8 is supposed to have a native implementation. IE7 doesn't.

If you're using a js toolkit like jquery or dojo, chances are it has it's own implementation of this so you might as well use that and avoid having to add yet another component to your codebase.

Comment: Note that if a quirks mode page is opened IE and it contains an iframe, that iframe will also be quirks mode and will not have the json lib. So JSON could be lacking even more recent IE versions if you don't control the parent frame a user is browsing you with.

Answer (score 27):

I had the issue with IE9.  IE9 was rendering my page in "quirks" mode, the solution was simply to add `<!DOCTYPE html>`.  This took me out of "quirks" mode which I'm sure fixed more than just this issue!

Comment: elegant and simple solution, +1

Comment: "quirks" mode?! Can you explain ?

Answer (score 19):

### Update

Check the [JSON3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/) library. It works like a charm.

[Changes from JSON2](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/#section_2)

I hope this helps.

---

Hope this helps. I got this from a few online sources long back. don't have their links.
 Sorry that i'm unable to cite references.

```
var JSON = JSON || {};
// implement JSON.stringify serialization
JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function(obj) {
    var t = typeof (obj);
    if (t != "object" || obj === null) {
        // simple data type
        if (t == "string")
            obj = '"' + obj + '"';
        return String(obj);
    } else {
        // recurse array or object
        var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);
        for (n in obj) {
            v = obj[n];
            t = typeof (v);
            if (t == "string")
                v = '"' + v + '"';
            else if (t == "object" && v !== null)
                v = JSON.stringify(v);
            json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
        }
        return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
    }
};
// implement JSON.parse de-serialization
JSON.parse = JSON.parse || function() {
    var r = "(?:-?\\b(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\\.[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?\\b)", k = '(?:[^\\0-\\x08\\x0a-\\x1f"\\\\]|\\\\(?:["/\\\\bfnrt]|u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}))';
    k = '(?:"' + k + '*")';
    var s = new RegExp(
            "(?:false|true|null|[\\{\\}\\[\\]]|" + r + "|" + k + ")", "g"), t = new RegExp(
            "\\\\(?:([^u])|u(.{4}))", "g"), u = {
        '"' : '"',
        "/" : "/",
        "\\" : "\\",
        b : "\u0008",
        f : "\u000c",
        n : "\n",
        r : "\r",
        t : "\t"
    };
    function v(h, j, e) {
        return j ? u[j] : String.fromCharCode(parseInt(e, 16));
    }
    var w = new String(""), x = Object.hasOwnProperty;
    return function(h, j) {
        h = h.match(s);
        var e, c = h[0], l = false;
        if ("{" === c)
            e = {};
        else if ("[" === c)
            e = [];
        else {
            e = [];
            l = true;
        }
        for ( var b, d = [ e ], m = 1 - l, y = h.length; m = 0;)
                            delete f[i[g]];
                }
                return j.call(n, o, f);
            };
            e = p({
                "" : e
            }, "");
        }
        return e;
    };
}();
```

Comment: Add this to the top of your js file. It'll use the native version if avl. If not, it uses the custom implementation.

Comment: Does it mean that JSON isn't implemented in IE and we need to code its parsing functionality by hand?!

Comment: Also, what do the parentheses at the end fill as a function? I'm not clear on why they are needed...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Legacy browsers don't have it implemented. Modern browsers do. I don't understand your 2nd question. Please be clear as to which part you're not clear about.

Comment: If you scroll all the way down in your code example, you'll see that there's `();` at the very end. I would expect just a curly brace, since you're declaring a function. What do I miss?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I just noticed that. Its definitely a copy-paste error. I'm very sorry. But I no longer have the actual source. I myself make use of the [JSON3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/) polyfill & recommend you to do the same.

Comment: JSON3? That's a new one. Didn't hear about it until now.

Answer (score 1):

To make your function works better in IE import JSON2 parser code in your file, as IE by default does not support `JSON.Stringify()`.

It can be found [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

Answer (score 0):

In IE open the compatibility view settings and remove the localhost from the listbox for "Websites you have added to Compatibility View". 
It worked for me.

Comment: IE7 doesnt support JSON `stringify` and `parse` methods, so OP really needs to use JSON2 library. Your answer is relevant for IE8 and later.

Comment: hundred times I fixed such JSON and other js errors in IE by manipulating compatibility settings, either removing sites frim compatibity list or disabling standard Microsoft list and intranet checkboxes. This comment makes sense, don't hesitate improving it and voting for it

Answer (score 0):

JQuery 2.x is no longer compatible with IE 6-8. [JQuery 2.0 beta 2 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/03/01/jquery-2-0-beta-2-released/)

I know the main question is in regard to older versions of JQuery, but this was causing the error for me. I installed JQuery 1.x, which is API-compatible with JQuery 2.x, and added the following detection code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```