# XDomainRequest POST with XML...what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, xml, wcf, post, xdomainrequest

This is (hopefully) an easy question.  I have to submit a request to a web service via POST with XDomainRequest.  I have found sparse documentation for this across the internet, but I refuse to believe that nobody has figured this out.

Here is my XDomainRequest code:

```
var testURL = 'http://localhost:4989/testendpoint';

//let us check to see if the browser is ie.  If it is not, let's 
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
    var xdr2 = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr2.open("POST", testURL);
    xdr2.timeout = 5000;
    xdr2.onerror = function () {
        alert('we had an error!');
    }
    xdr2.onprogress = function () { 
        alert('we have some progress!');
    };
    xdr2.onload = function () {
        alert('we load the xdr!');

        var xml2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xml2.async = true;
        xml2.loadXML(xdr2.responseText);
    };

    //what form should my request take to be sending a string for a POST request?  
    xdr2.send("thisisastring");
}
```

My web service (WCF) takes a single parameter according to the web service's help page, that looks like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">String content</string>
```

I've gotten this to work via other http clients (mobile and desktop APIs, fiddler) by building a string that concatenates the parameter I am trying to pass to the web service with the rest of the string serialization.  For example, I have tried:

```
xdr2.send("thisisastring");
xdr2.send("<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">thisisastring</string>");
```

but the onerror handler is always tripped.  I don't think it has anything to do with the WCF because:

- The WCF is always successful in every other client I call it from,
  and
- If it was the service, the onerror method would never get tripped. 
  It would return garbage, but it would be returning something.

When i use the console (in the dev tools in ie9) to log the responseText, it says:

```
LOG:undefined
```

So I am fairly sure that the issue is in how I use the XDomainRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody comes across this, I ended up converting my web services to return JSON-formatted data.  Using JSON negates the need for XDomainRequest, allowing me to use the conventional ajax jquery tools instead.

Comment: did u get the solution for this. i am facing same problem.

Comment: Nope.  I changed jobs before I had to build out the POST requirements.    For the rest of it, I converted it to JSON.  Not sure if you can POST to JSON or not in IE, but I was going to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093582/json-is-undefined-error-in-ie-only before I changed jobs.  Sorry!