# what is the json data format ie understands?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am calling a php script to get the data using ajax. It works without any problems on chrome and other browsers but on IE (of course) it does not work.

My data format is as follows:

```
[1234000000000,56]
```

this is the script I am trying to call to get the abobe value:

```
$.ajax({

        url: 'get_cpu.php', 
        success: function(data) {
          var myObj = JSON.parse(data); 
                        alert(obj);
```

I tried outputing this file in many different formats to make IE happpy without any luck. How can I format this data in json so that ie understands? I really appreciate any insight?

Best regards,

Comment: What's the error message? The JSON seems valid.

Comment: Which version of IE, how are you trying to parse the JSON?  I don't think IE 8 has the built-in `JSON.parse` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old versions of IE don't have the built-in `JSON` object.  Therefore, `JSON.parse` doesn't exist.  It has nothing to do with your JSON format.

Since you are using jQuery, you don't need to worry JSON parsing; it will take care of it.  In your `$.ajax` call, add `dataType: 'json'`.  This will make jQuery parse it for you automatically.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_cpu.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

If you weren't using jQuery, you would have to use a `JSON` replacement library, like [`json3.js`](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/).

Comment: @user1471980: *What* is undefined?  I want to see the *entire* string.  For example: `ReferenceError: xyz is not defined`.

Comment: when I run this in chrome, I get this: [1371206178000, 55] , in IE I get this: LOG:undefined

Comment: @user1471980: Oh.  Sorry.  That's not an error, just the log's output.  Is this what you get with the *exact* code in my answer (you did remove the `JSON.parse` line, and add `dataType: 'json'`, right)?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code exactly. As you can see from chrome, it works, but not in IE

Comment: this is the entire ajax section: $.ajax({
    url: 'get_cpu.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        },
        cache: false
  
    });

Comment: I am using jquery.min.js, do you think I should use the full version for json?

Comment: @user1471980: That is the "full" version of jQuery, it's just "minified".  What version of jQuery are you using?  The 2.x series doesn't support old versions of IE, you should be using 1.9.x.

Comment: @user1471980: I'm curious.  Can you change the `success` function to `function(data, status, jqXHR){ console.log(jqXHR.responseText); }` and show me what gets printed?  Because I tested this in IE8 and it worked for me.  P.S. What version of IE are you using?  They are all completely different.

Comment: I get this: LOG: undefined

Comment: @user1471980: Hmm?  I don't know what to tell ya.  This is all working for me in IE8.  As a last-ditch effort, try `$.getJSON('get_cpu.php', function(data){ console.log(data); });`/

Comment: @user1471980: Sorry.  I got nothing else.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @user1471980: 1.9.1.  What version are *you* using?

Comment: I am using 1.8.2. I saw this post http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13169, do you think this might be it?

Comment: @user1471980: What version of IE are you using?  What does IE's dev tools say for "Document Mode" and "Browser Mode"?

Comment: I tried this with IE8 and iE9, the same issue. I get the Log:undefined error. it is crazy, dont know what to do.

Comment: do you think I have put something like this in my php script: header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: @user1471980: You could try that :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh923971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). All of code there runs in all browsers.

Comment: and also here it is solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093582/json-is-undefined-error-in-ie-only