# Error JSON is undefined

Tags: javascript

I had this error on internet explorer `'JSON' is undefined`.

The error occurred here:

```
ajaxCall({
    url: me.getAllService,
    data: JSON.stringify(unionParameters({ filter: filter }, getData(), me.getAllParameters)),
    success: function (result) {
        if (typeof (onSuccess) == 'function')
            onSuccess(result);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        if (typeof (onFailed) == 'function')
            onFailed(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you know if the version of internet explorer you're using supports the object `JSON`?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['JSON' is undefined error in IE only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093582/json-is-undefined-error-in-ie-only)

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON` parsing features appeared in IE8. If you are using IE7 or earlier, `JSON` will be undefined.

Additionally, if you are using IE8, it must be in standards mode. In quirks mode, the `JSON` formatter will not be available.

In any event, there are polyfills available so that you can use the `JSON` formatter in those situations. Scroll down to "JavaScript" at http://www.json.org/ for four possibilities.

Sources/additional information:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=json
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

use JSON2. It is the polyfill you need

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/json2

Answer (score 0):

> I solved this problem by adding this lines of code in master page :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```